# how can we generate auto id with .NET

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

i would facing a problem while working in C#. AS i have to generate an ID which is automatically when user clicks on ADD button

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you will be adding a row to a database table when the user clicks an ADD button, and you want the row to get an automatically-generated ID.

Simply add an IDENTITY column. You should probably make it the primary key, as well:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MORE_DATA] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```

Comment: Probably not relevant to the OP, but note that using identity columns like this has problems with scaleability (with respect to merge replication), you may be better off using a guid (set as uniqueidentifier).

Comment: Is merge replication the only scalability issue with identity columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the schema, do what @John Saunders says.
If you have to make your own identify for some reason, try using a [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx).

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
```